# Separating output (Separating output from input by one line)

Tags: python-3.x, output

So I made this code. (Don't think about the input questions, it's part of a program.)

```
indexes = 1223314123
s = 'My hobby is computing'
now = input("Do you want to compress or decompress? ")
now = now.lower()
if now == 'compress':
    print(indexes)
    nows = input ("Do you want to decompress the file as well? If you do, please enter 'yes', or if you don't want to please enter 'no' ")
    nows = nows.lower()
    if nows == 'yes':
        print (s)
    elif nows == 'no':
        print ("Thank you for your time!")
    else:
        print ("Please try again!")
elif now == 'decompress':
    print(s)
    nowss = input ("Do you want to compress the file as well? If you do, please enter 'yes', or if you don't want to please enter 'no' ")
    nowss = nowss.lower()
    if nowss == 'yes':
        print (indexes)
    elif nows == 'no':
        print ("Thank you for your time!")
    else:
        print ("Please try again") 
else:
    print ("Please try again!")
```

And the output works like this

```
Do you want to compress or decompress? decompress
My hobby is computing
Do you want to compress the file as well? If you do, please enter 'yes', or 
if you don't want to please enter 'no' YEs
1223314123
```

Do any of you guys know a way in which the output can be made to come out like this-

```
Do you want to compress or decompress? decompress
My hobby is computing

Do you want to compress the file as well? If you do, please enter 'yes', or if you don't want to please enter 'no' YEs
1223314123
```

So, that whenever the program asks for an input, it's separated by a line from whatever it done/outputted earlier. It is for clarity of reading, since if 'indexes' and 's' were bigger paragraphs it would be extremely difficult to find out where that output has gone if one wants to find it again.